# C++: sum of columns of a dynamic 2D vector

Tags: c++

In C++, how to use a two-dimensional dynamic vector to sum up each column for the matrix in the txt file, and print out the content of the txt file and the result of summing up each column?

After searching through the Internet, I got the following code, but it only sums up a single column. The result I want to get is that no matter how many columns there are in the txt file, I can do the sum of each column.

[data.txt figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebtgv.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

ifstream myfile("data.txt");

if (!myfile.is_open()) {
    cout << "Unable to open myfile";
    system("pause");
    exit(0);

}

vector<string> vec;
string temp;


while (getline(myfile, temp))                    
{
    vec.push_back(temp);
}

vector <float> radius;


cout << "Processing time: " << endl;
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++)
{
    cout << *it << endl;
    istringstream is(*it);                    
    string s;
    int pam = 0;

    while (is >> s)                  
    {
        if (pam == 0)                    

        {
            float r = atof(s.c_str());     
            radius.push_back(r);

        }


        pam++;

    }
}
cout << "matrix: " << endl;

double sum;
sum = 0;
for (auto it = radius.begin(); it != radius.end(); it++)
{
    sum += *it;  
}
cout << sum << endl;


system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

I want to sum each column in the txt file, as shown in the image below:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUyY9.png)

Comment: If possible when working with containers try to avoid "raw loops" eg. `#include <numeric>` and `std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(),0);` (similar for radius). If you need to sum over a column create a view on that

Comment: I want to sum each column in the txt file, like the result picture above, how can I do it?

Comment: @Hana How are the columns separated in each line?

Comment: @delock I just add spaces in the txt file by myself

Comment: @Hana -- *I want to sum each column in the txt file* -- At this stage, does it matter where the numbers come from?  You should write a very simple `main` program: `int main() { std::vector<std::vector<float>> test = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};` and given that, write a function that sums up the columns of `temp`.  All of this stuff with files are not important at this point.  Once you get that simple program to work, then you introduce all of the file handling.  That's how a programmer would approach this problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Because the number in the txt file is not always the same, it may be 3*6 this time, 5*4 the next time, and the number will not be known, so it is impossible to directly declare the number in the file

Comment: @Hana -- It doesn't matter what the number is.  Please read my comment more carefully, especially this part -- *write a function*.  The function also doesn't know how many columns there are.  All it knows that whatever data it is given, it returns back a vector of totals.  The function doesn't care where, when, or how the data is created.  Its sole responsibility is when given a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`, it returns a properly sized `total` vector.  Once you have that function, the rest of the code is easy.

Comment: `std::vector<float> getTotals(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& myData) { 
    std::vector<float> totals(myData[0].size());..you fill this in; return totals;}` -- That is basically what you should be attempting to do.  The part that says `you fill this in` is exactly what I am referring to.  Once you have that function completed, that is 90% of the job done.  Then the only thing left is to properly construct the `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` from the file, and then pass that vector to the function.  Again, this is how a developer writes proper code.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is not concern yourself with where the data is coming from.  Instead, you should write a function that takes the data, regardless of where it comes from, and outputs the totals.

The simplest way to represent the input data is to use a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`.  Thus a function to create the totals would return a `std::vector<float>` that represents the totals.

Here is an example of such a function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

// Pass in the data    
std::vector<float> getTotals(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& myData)
{
    std::vector<float> totals(myData[0].size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < totals.size(); ++i)
    {
        // call std::accumulate for each column i
        totals[i] = std::accumulate(myData.begin(), myData.end(), 0, 
                                   [&](int total, auto& v)
                                   { return total + v[i]; });
    }
    // return the totals
    return totals;
}
```

The above function uses [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to total the values in column `i`, and store the total for that column in `totals[i]`.

Once this function is written, it can then be tested.  Here is a full example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<float> getTotals(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& myData)
{
    std::vector<float> totals(myData[0].size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < totals.size(); ++i)
    {
        totals[i] = std::accumulate(myData.begin(), myData.end(), 0, 
         [&](int total, auto& v)
         { return total + v[i]; });
    }
    return totals;
}

void printTotals(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& data, 
                 const std::vector<float>& totals)
{
    for (auto& v : data)
    {
        for (auto& v2 : v)
            std::cout << v2 << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Total: ";
    for (auto& t : totals)
        std::cout << t << " ";
}

int main() 
{ 
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> test1 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> test2 = {{1,2,3,4},{4,5,6,8},{7,8,9,10}};
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> test3 = {{1,2},{-3,4},{7,8},{34,12},{12,17}};
    printTotals(test1, getTotals(test1));
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    printTotals(test2, getTotals(test2));
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    printTotals(test3, getTotals(test3));
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
Total: 12 15 18 

1 2 3 4 
4 5 6 8 
7 8 9 10 
Total: 12 15 18 22 

1 2 
-3 4 
7 8 
34 12 
12 17 
Total: 51 43
```

---

Once you have this, the next step is to create the `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` from the data in the file.  Once that is created, it is just a simple matter of calling the getTotals() function with that data.

The file reading can be as follows:

```
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//...
std::vector<std::vector<float>> readData(std::istream& is)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;
    std::string oneLine;
    float oneData;
    while (std::getline(is, oneLine))    
    {
        std::vector<float> vOneData;
        std::istringstream  strm(oneLine);
        while (strm >> oneData)
            vOneData.push_back(oneData);
        data.push_back(vOneData);
    }
    return data;
}
```

The function is called by simply passing in the stream object (in your case, `myfile`).  The returned value will be a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` of the values that were read in.

Putting this all together:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<float> getTotals(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& myData)
{
    std::vector<float> totals(myData[0].size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < totals.size(); ++i)
    {
        totals[i] = std::accumulate(myData.begin(), myData.end(), 0, 
         [&](int total, auto& v)
         { return total + v[i]; });
    }
    return totals;
}

void printTotals(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& data, 
                 const std::vector<float>& totals)
{
    for (auto& v : data)
    {
        for (auto& v2 : v)
            std::cout << v2 << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Total: ";
    for (auto& t : totals)
        std::cout << t << " ";
}

std::vector<std::vector<float>> readData(std::istream& is)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;
    std::string oneLine;
    float oneData;
    while (std::getline(is, oneLine))    
    {
        std::vector<float> vOneData;
        std::istringstream  strm(oneLine);
        while (strm >> oneData)
            vOneData.push_back(oneData);
        data.push_back(vOneData);
    }
    return data;
}

int main() 
{ 
    std::string fileData = "2 3 4 1 5 2\n6 1 2 6 1 8\n8 7 3 9 6 4";
    std::istringstream fileDataStream(fileData);
    auto dataFromFile = readData(fileDataStream);
    printTotals(dataFromFile, getTotals(dataFromFile));
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 4 1 5 2 
6 1 2 6 1 8 
8 7 3 9 6 4 
Total: 16 11 9 16 12 14
```

Note that I didn't use a file stream, but a `stringstream` to illustrate it doesn't matter how the data is created.

Comment: So, if I want to read the file from the file and do the calculation, can I make changes from the main?
For example: string fileData = "data.txt";
I tried this and it just prints "Total:"
Is there something wrong with my thinking?

Comment: `ifstream myfile("data.txt");` and assuming `myfile` is opened successfully: `auto dataFromFile = readData(myfile);`.  I don't know what you were doing, but you can see that the `readData` takes a file stream, not a string.

Comment: Sorry, I just started to contact C++, so I don't know how to operate it very well, so where should I put the path of the txt file in the code, so that the file can be read?
Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: The code you posted already did this: `ifstream myfile("data.txt");` -- so I don't know what the issue is that you're having by simply taking that `myfile` and calling `readData(myfile);`.  I suggest taking the code in the answer, compile it, run it.  Once you do that replace the lines that read the data in from a stringstream, and use `myfile`, just as I illustrated.  It is basically foolproof.

Comment: And if you want another example, [see this](https://godbolt.org/z/MzbP3954d).  That takes the input from the keyboard, (`std::cin`), which is also a stream object.  A `std::ifstream`is a stream object, `std::cin` is an input stream object, a `std::istringstream` is a stream object, etc.  It doesn't matter what type the input stream object is.  So I really don't understand why you're having this trouble.